# how to discern the meaning although in the sentence below?

Tags: conjunctions

Would you please through a reason show me which of the bold parts related to the sentence below? Why don't we call it ***conflict***?

**comparison** **contrast** **conflict**

Although in poor health, she continue to carry out her duties.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use **carry on** which fits better in your example.

> In **contrast** with her poor health she continues to carry on her duties.

That is she doesn't stop doing her duties regardless of her illness.

Comment: I think the question is whether the sentence is using a comparison, contrast, or conflict.

Comment: @mkennedy,That's correct, and my answer says it is describing a *contrasting* situation. Nevertheless a slight note of comparison and conflictual status can be drawn as well but the main idea is of contrast.